# Why scanner return extra code when using javascript to handle barcode scanning?

Tags: javascript, barcode

When I scan barcodes with a barcode scanner, the char code returned are more than it should be.

I am trying to use a barcode scanner to scan some barcodes I generated. I need to use Javascript to catch the barcode I scanned. 
However, if I allow the scanner directly input into a textbox or txt file, it would be fine, but if I catch the char code that scanner returned, I found there are some extra codes mixed into the original one. e.g.
Barcode code is E9C2GUEST1
When input to textbox, it is E9C2GUEST1,
When catch charcode and transfer, it becomes: 069E0579067C0502071G085U069E083S084T0491
As we can see, there are some code like "069", "057", "067", "050", "071", "085", "069", "083", "084", and "049" are mixed with the original code.
Is there anyone know what are they? and is there any solution to remove them?

```
function ConfigCodeScanning() {
    var lastTime = null, currentTime = null;
    var lastCode = null, currentCode = null;
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        currentCode = e.charCode;
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (currentTime - lastTime <= 30 || lastTime == null) {
            //DO scanner input
            $("#participantBarcode").val($("#participantBarcode").val() + String.fromCharCode(currentCode));
        } else {
            //DO nothing
        }
        lastCode = currentCode;
        lastTime = currentTime;
    });
}
```

Comment: Where does that weird string come from? And why the asterisks? The "extra" numbers are the char codes of the barcode's characters. 69 = "E", 57 = "9" etc.

Comment: can you please share your full code in js fiddle so we can get batter idea

Comment: If you configure the scanner to append ENTER after each barcode read, does that make this code moot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the numbers like `067`before the values like `C` point to the decimal values in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For your example data, if the you could match a zero followed by 2 digits and replace it with an empty string.

```
0\d{2}
```

```js
const regex = /0\d{2}/g;
const str = `069E0579067C0502071G085U069E083S084T0491`;
const result = str.replace(regex, '');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am sorry to cause the misunderstanding. I added the "*" manually to following the stackoverflow format to high light the char that should be the correct one. There shouldn't be any "*" in the output.

Comment: @Ternence.Lin I am not sure what you mean. Is the source string not correct? Does it not contain an asterix `*`

Comment: Barcode code is E9C2GUEST1
When input to textbox, it is E9C2GUEST1,
When catch barcode scanner input and use var str += String.fromCharCode(code) it becomes: 069E0579067C0502071G085U069E083S084T0491

Comment: @Ternence.Lin  have updated my answer. Are the character always uppercase?

Comment: Yes, due to the barcode generating policy, it will always be uppercase. Thank you so much. I will try it.